# Running two functions in parallel and then calling another function with result of prev functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

My javascript code..

```
function testdata(){
    var strtest_data='';
    var strtest1_data='';
    d3.json("js/test.json").then(function(test_json) {
        strtest_data=JSON.stringify(test_json);
       console.log(strtest_data); 
    })
    d3.json("js/test.json").then(function(test_json1) {
        strtest1_data=JSON.stringify(test_json1);
       console.log(strtest_data1); 
    })
     console.log(strtest_data); 
     var testobj=JSON.parse(strtest_data);
     var testobj1=JSON.parse(strtest_data1);
   
   console.log(JSON.stringify({data:testobj.quiz, more:testobj1.maths}));
}
```

In the above code I'm calling two functions using d3.json (for brevity in this question I'm calling for the same test.json) and then with the results calling another function. Here the function is console.log but in actual scenario could be a ajax POST call using fetch.

The above code does not work as the bottom part of the code gets run prior to d3.json getting finished..

I would sincerely appreciate any help in solving this.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest promise.all for your ajax calls and then you can have both results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d3.json` is asynchronous method, so if you want to call it sequentially, use `async/await`

```
async function testdata() {
  let strtest_data = ""
  let strtest1_data = ""

  const test_json = await d3.json("js/test.json")
  strtest_data = JSON.stringify(test_json)
  console.log(strtest_data)

  const test_json1 = await d3.json("js/test.json")
  strtest1_data = JSON.stringify(test_json1)
  console.log(strtest_data1)

  var testobj = JSON.parse(strtest_data)
  var testobj1 = JSON.parse(strtest_data1)

  console.log(JSON.stringify({ data: testobj.quiz, more: testobj1.maths }))
}
```

or call it concurently using `Promise.all`

```
async function testdata() {
  let strtest_data = ""
  let strtest1_data = ""

  const [test_json, test_json1] = await Promise.all([
    d3.json("js/test.json"),
    d3.json("js/test.json"),
  ])
  strtest_data = JSON.stringify(test_json)
  strtest1_data = JSON.stringify(test_json1)
  console.log(strtest_data)
  console.log(strtest_data1)

  var testobj = JSON.parse(strtest_data)
  var testobj1 = JSON.parse(strtest_data1)

  console.log(JSON.stringify({ data: testobj.quiz, more: testobj1.maths }))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just trying to understand..., Here you have used const. If I used var and not use Stringify and Parse, I should be able to use test_json.quiz and test_json1.maths in final console.log. Is doing this ok or is using var not right is this circumstance..

Comment: @Arnab using var is still ok in this circumstance. I just use let/const as my own practice

Answer (score 0):

Here I think

```
 Promise.all([    d3.json("js/test.json")
    d3.json("js/test.json")].then(data =>{
//call your other function and access using data array and make your call 
}).catch(e=>console.error("error ",e));
```

This function is going to execute both calls when they finish then it will put the result in data array. If any error comes in either of the call you will have it in the catch block. You can do whatever you want to in the then block if all calls are completed successfully.